# Grub to multiple bios options

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am fairly a beginner to Linux, I had a windows and Ubuntu dual boot, recently I think I did something inappropriate in the hope of expanding my main drive, now I had to repair the boot options through boot repair utility, and it shows grub now. But I want multiple boot options rather than grub since I rarely use windows but I do and rather than being given the options I prefer going into my asus bios and reordering with gui to boot windows.

TLDR:
Please suggest a way to have windows and Ubuntu as seperate bios boot options from being grub

Edit: I had this config before this problem so I don't think it is not possible.

Comment: It is designed to use Grub but you can make a permanent change to the boot order that Grub presents. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/grub-customizer here is the link to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: I am afraid no.